# How to configure rtl8723be to detect wifi networks (solved for HP laptop)

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, network-manager, 15.10, realtek-wireless

This condition is associated with:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1240940

I am using a rlt8723 wifi card with Kubuntu 15.10.

The card is configured as shown:

ifconfig:

```
wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:77:81:32:3b:17  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

iwconfig:

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

results of `rfkill list wifi` are

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
```

`lsmod|grep rtl8723` shows:

```
rtl8723be              86016  0
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723be
mac80211              733184  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
```

however net-manager does not detect wireless networks and running

`iwlist wlps30 scan` as root gives "no results".

If I boot into Windows 10, there are multiple networks detected,hardware working correctly.

Network manager settings from wireless info tool:

```
`##### network managers ##################

Installed:

NetworkManager

Running:

root       784     1  0 19:56 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin /NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek   Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8723be
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.2.0-23-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         42 (The supplicant is now available)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/wlp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########`
```

Is there another setting which needs to be configured?

Update 1/20/2016:  using linux-image-4.2.0-25
tried loading rtl8723be module with:
  `modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=1`

and

`modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2`

no success in getting WIFI card to detect networks.
for reference see

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/34

Comment: Yeah, I'm not used with this SystemD nomenclature yet. For me it's the good ol' Upstart wlan0 and eth0 in 14.04. Why don't you google something like `Ubuntu 15.10 rtl8723 wlp3s0`? There's probably a documentation entry about it.

Comment: Another HP computer? Also just try `iwlist scan`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to successfully scan for networks after completing the steps below on an HP 11" Pavilion X360 model 11-k020nr. Apparently the rtl8723 can have two antenna but HP only installs one in the laptop.  The rtl8723be driver needs to have the correct antenna assigned or the wifi reception is too poor to detect networks.

download drive source files at:
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

There is a "Download Zip" button, in the top 1/3 of the web-page on the right side.

Extract the .zip into any folder.  A "rtlwifi_new-master" folder will be created.

Enter the "rtlwifi_new-master" folder and run:

`make clean
sudo make install`

Once the code is compiled and installed:

`sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
 sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be isp=0 ant_sel=2`

run

`sudo iwlist wlp3s0 scan`

to see if networks are detected.  One might have to try ant_sel=1.  I confirmed that Bluetooth still works.

If it helps, make it permanent:

`sudo -i
 echo "options rtl8723be isp=0 ant_sel=1"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf 
 exit`

Comment: I am on Kubuntu 17.10 beta final. I did not need to download/compile the rtlwifi_new. Just the below command works.  sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be isp=0 ant_sel=2